# Difference between update() and columns_updated()

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

My table definition:

```
create table cust
(
     cid int identity,
     cnm varchar(100),
     country varchar(100)
)

alter table cust 
  add constraint pk primary key clustered on cust(cid)
```

I am trying to create an audit record only when cnm or country column is updated.

My 2 queries:

```
create trigger trig_nm on cust
as
    if columns_updated(cnm, country)
    --create records.

create trigger trig_nm on cust
as
    if update(cnm) or update(country)
       --create records.
```

What is the difference between 2 queries?

Comment: That's not how [`COLUMNS_UPDATED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) works, so one is a syntax error and the other isn't?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to use like this `columns_updated(cnm,country)`

The `COLUMNS_UPDATED` function returns `varbinary` and you need some bitwise calculation to identify which column(s) are updated.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329(v=sql.110).aspx),

> COLUMNS_UPDATED returns one or more bytes that are ordered from left
>   to right, with the least significant bit in each byte being the
>   rightmost.
>
> To test for
>   updates or inserts to specific columns, follow the syntax with a
>   bitwise operator and an integer bitmask of the columns being tested.
>   For example, table t1 contains columns C1, C2, C3, C4, and C5. To
>   verify that columns C2, C3, and C4 are all updated (with table t1
>   having an UPDATE trigger), follow the syntax with & 14. To test
>   whether only column C2 is updated, specify & 2.

You have to use like this for checking whether the columns 2,3 and 4 are updated

```
IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 14) > 0
--Create Records
```

For `UPDATE()` function, it returns `Boolean` if the given column is updated.

You can use this like,

```
IF ( UPDATE(cnm) OR UPDATE(Country))
--Create records
```